# CAS Authentication failed phpCAS

Tags: php, phpcas

I get error, after successful login in CAS.

`CAS Authentication failed! You were not authenticated.You may submit your request again by clicking here. If the problem persists, you may contact the administrator of this site.`

and the error in Log file :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'CAS_AuthenticationException' in /var/www/CAS-.3.2/CAS/Client.php:2764\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/CAS-1.3.2/CAS/Client.php(1224): CAS_Client->validateCAS20('https://sso.jarko...', '', NULL)\n#1 /var/www/CAS-1.3.2/CAS.php(1151): CAS_Client->isAuthenticated()\n#2 /var/www/login.php(8): phpCAS::isAuthenticated()\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/CAS-1.3.2/CAS/Client.php on line 2764,
```

any one can help me....??
please

Comment: If it's an error, what makes you think your login was successful? Not really much to go on here without more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error before.
I solved the problem after i configure tomcat ssl using keytool of java-7.

Steps:

1. create store
2. create cert
3. import keystore into java-7